# Entity retrieve method should retrieve entities with cancelled property equal to false

Tags: c#, properties, repository

All entities are derived from a `BaseEntity` which has a `Cancelled` property of type `bool`. I am modifying the `GetList` method in the repository class which retrieves entities using

```
public static IList<T> GetList<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : BaseEntity
```

predicate as method parameter (where `T` is derived from `BaseEntity`). I know it is possible to make a new method `GetListNonCancelled` and add a `Where` clause to existing query like

```
query.Where(e => e.Cancelled == false)
```

which will return me list of entities which have `Cancelled` property set to `false`, but if an entity has property which is also a entity derived from `BaseEntity` or an array of entities derived from `BaseEntity`, how it is possible to add where clause to search query to specify that it should also retrieve only entities with `Cancelled` property set to `false`?

Example

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public bool Cancelled { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Entity1 : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Entity3 Child { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2 : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Entity3> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Entity3 : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So when I want to retrieve a list of entities of type `Entity1` I should get only entities which have `Cancelled` property set to `false`, and also if property `Child` entity has `Cancelled` set to `false` it should be retrieved, otherwise it should be null.

For `Entity2`, `IList<Entity3>` children should contain only entities with `Cancelled` set to `false`.

I am trying to use reflection to determine if property of entity has base type equal to `BaseEntity`

```
if (property.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(BaseEntity))
```

but how can I add it to query?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. You should be able to linq query against properties of a parent class without issue. Is this not working for you?

Comment: Yes, I can use query, but what if I want to release developer from manually specifying e.Cancelled == false and do that automatically inside GetListNonCancelled method?